# Replacing data source of annotation feature classes using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, annotation, personal-geodatabase, data-source

I want to batch replace paths in a series of `.mxd` files using Python. Many of the layers have moved and in some cases the name has changed or its dataset is different.

I've written this code which takes an Excel file with two columns (one column for the old path and one column for the new path) and converts to a dictionary. Then I iterate through the layers in my `.mxd` files, and iterate through the dictionary, using `replaceDataSource` to change the data sources.

The trouble is this won't work with annotation feature classes. I've added in a try/except with `findAndReplaceWorkspacePath` to see if that may work (I don't believe the annotation layers/names have changed), but the code still doesn't address those layers.

One thing to note is that the annotation feature classes are stored in a personal geodatabase, but I don't know if this could be causing any issues.

I am hoping someone has ideas on code that will work to change the path of the annotation feature classes!

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd, arcpy, os

mxd_path = r'C:\temp\Chapters'

d = {}
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('U:\GIS\Chevron_Lokern\Projects\Figures_Update_2014\Lokern_Source_Paths_KL.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(293):
  cell_value_class = sh.cell(i,0).value
  cell_value_id = sh.cell(i,1).value
  d[cell_value_class] = cell_value_id

  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mxd_path):
    for filename in filenames:
      fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
      if filename[-4:] == ".mxd":
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
        print filename

        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
                #print lyr.datasetName
                for k,v in d.iteritems():
                    #print k,v
                    k_path, k_name = os.path.split(k)
                    v_path, v_name = os.path.split(v)
                    if lyr.dataSource == k and k != v:
                        #print 'KEY:',k,'VAL:',v, 'NAME:',v_name
                        try:
                            print 'trying to change data source for',lyr.dataSource
                            lyr.replaceDataSource(v_path,'FILEGDB_WORKSPACE',v_name,True)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print 'can\'t replace',lyr.dataSource, e
                            try:
                                print 'trying to change data source for',lyr.dataSource
                                lyr.replaceDataSource(v_path,'RASTER_WORKSPACE',v_name,True)
                            except Exception as e:
                                print 'still can\'t replace',lyr.dataSource, e
                                try:
                                    print 'trying to change data source for',lyr.dataSource
                                    lyr.replaceDataSource(v_path,'SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE',v_name,True)
                                except Exception as e:
                                    print 'still can\'t replace',lyr.dataSource, e
                                    try:
                                        print 'trying to change data source for',lyr.dataSource
                                        lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(k_path,v_path)
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        print 'can\'t replace workspace path for',lyr.datasetName, e
        mxd.relativePaths = 'True'
        mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: Annotation layers are unique. This is a method I used for accessing their datasource.

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53913/using-arcpy-describe-method-on-annotation-layers/90229#90229