# Removing annotation layer according to data source using ArcPy gives NameError?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, annotation, nameerror, remove

I work with this FGB annotation (ArcView 10.3):

[image]
[image]

and i try to remove it with this code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\road611\gis\aa"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
   print mxdname 
   fullPath = env.workspace + "\\" + mxdname
   if 'env_70-42' not in mxdname:
      mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
      df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
      for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*",df):
         if lyr.isGroupLayer == True: continue
         if lyr.dataSource == r"G:\PROJECTS\road611\gis\lyr\18_8_16\New File Geodatabase.gdb\anno":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
            print 'RemoveLayer'
      mxd.save()
      counter = counter + 1  
del mxd
```

but i failed to remove the layer and i get this error:

```
NameError: The attribute 'dataSource' is not supported on this instance of Layer
```

but if i remove manually the "anno" feature class, and try to remove other FGD feature class, then i succeed and get this:

```
>>> 
antiquities_70-42.mxd
RemoveLayer
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to ask if the layer supports `dataSource`, then set it.  There are lots of layer types and only a few support the dataSource property.

Your code is just skipping group layers.

Try something like:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*",df):
  if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
    if lyr.dataSource == r"G:\PROJECTS\road611\gis\lyr\18_8_16\New File Geodatabase.gdb\anno":
      arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
      print 'RemoveLayer'
mxd.save()
```

See the [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm#M2_GUID-AE1B6592-5077-4B14-AFF1-BE41E81538CC) for the Supports method for more details.

If you are trying to access the dataSource for the annotation, see this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90229/43) to [Using arcpy.Describe Method on Annotation layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/53913/115).